# PWA application -> geolaction dosn't work

Tags: geolocation, progressive-web-apps, quasar

I have problem with geoloaction in my PWA application. Sometimes when I open my app the location is not detect(location allowed and internet is running). But when I open google maps application and return to my application then the location starts working!

I don't what is going on and how I can fix it. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?